# How to replace all periods in a string in JavaScript without /g?

Tags: javascript, regex, firebase, replace, firebase-realtime-database

I want to replace periods in a string with %20 for Firebase key purposes. I can do 1 period at a time with:

```
string.replace('.', '%20')
```

I can even do all of them with a `/g` regex flag:

```
string.replace(/\./g, '%20')
```

But Firebase rules gives me an error:

> Error saving rules - Line 5: regular expressions do not support flags other than i

So I need an expression that replaces all periods without using `/g`. I could just chain `.replace('.', '%20')` a bunch of times:

```
string.replace('.', '%20').replace('.', '%20').replace('.', '%20').replace('.', '%20')
```

But I'm hoping there's a better way.

**UPDATE**: I had tried `string.split('.').join('%20')`, but Firebase throws the error:

> Type error: Function call on target that is not a function.

I guess they took out the `split` function in their JSON rules parser.

**UPDATE 2**: I also tried `(function() {var s = auth.token.email; while (s.indexOf('.') != -1) { s = s.replace('.', '%20') } return s})()`. Firebase complained that function definitions are not allowed in their database rules.

**UPDATE 3**: Thanks to Firebase's wonderful support, I found out that the `string.replace` function in their database rules has been *replaced* with a version that replaces **all** occurrences of the substring, not just a single occurrence. So actually `string.replace('.', %2E')` works perfectly!

Comment: The only reference I found to that is this [Github Issue](https://github.com/firebase/bolt/issues/176)…

Comment: Yes @Xufox that's the issue I'm dealing with

Comment: If you are planning on using email addresses as keys, there are WAY better options to structure your data so this mess can be avoided completely. Just sayin'.

Comment: @Jay thank you for the suggestion, but there are good reasons we're using email addresses as keys

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just split and join it again `string.split('.').join('%20')`

Comment: Plus1 for saving me having to type the exact same thing :D

Comment: That’s elegant! My first thought was a `while` loop with `(/\./).test(string)` or something similar as the condition.

Comment: Was just posting an update that I tried this but Firebase gives me an error. It is a good answer to my question though.

Comment: This is in fact not a very performant solution. You can use replaceAll in new browsers and potentially RegExp might be faster than split and join.

Comment: @KemalTezerDilsiz thanks for the heads up on the new method! I don't think that was available when I originally answered, but good to know :)

Answer (score 1):

Since Firebase is complaining when you also try the obviously better answer of split then join, try this...

```js
var s = "this.is.a.string.value";

while (s.indexOf(".") != -1) {
  s = s.replace(".", "%20");
}

console.log(s);
```

Comment: I can try wrapping that as an expression or an IIFE

Comment: Yeah, you know the context so you can decide the best way to use it.  If you can prototype functions in Firebase then that may be a solution, if you need it more than once.

Comment: Unfortunately Firebase gives an error that function definitions are not allowed in database rules :(